# changing date/time string format javascript

Tags: javascript

I know there are many functions in javascript that changes the date format, but I want to change the format of the string.

How can I change

`2018-05-10T21:12:08Z`

to

`2018-05-10 9:12:08 AM`

The date function doesn't work since it's not a date type.

Comment: I would probably get each part of the date individually first. (year/month/day) then get the time (h:m:s) then get the am/pm part. That way you can format each part and then concatenate them much easier. Start here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

Comment: Look into `Date.parse()` first, or you can use an external library like `moment.js`

Comment: Turn the string into a `Date`, turn the `Date` into a string…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [moment](https://momentjs.com) library to do all kind of date/time operations.

```
var dt = moment('2018-05-10T21:12:08Z');
console.log(dt.format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A'));
```